# Se cierra la aplicación cuando uso la cámara de fotos en un fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, cámara, fragment

Estoy intentando hacer mi primera app para android (bastante novato) y tengo un problema y ya no veo la luz por ningún sitio:

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la que quiero capturar una imagen con la cámara y ponerla en un `ImageView` en un `Fragment`. En el método. El fragment se carga correctamente, la cámara se abre, pero al aceptar la imagen se cierra la aplicación.

En el método `onCreate` del activity principal llamo a otro activity (también con `OnActivityResult`) que hace un login.

El código para abrir la cámara en el fragment:

```
 img = (ImageView)viewPrincipal.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
     Button btn_hacerfoto = (Button) viewPrincipal.findViewById(R.id.botonCamara);
    //Añadimos el Listener Boton
    btn_hacerfoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent =  new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            int code = HACER_FOTO;
            nombreFoto = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/test.jpg";
                intent.putExtra("ventana","foto");
                Uri output = Uri.fromFile(new File(nombreFoto));
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, output);
                startActivityForResult(intent, code);
        }
    });
```

En el fragment el método `OnActivityResult`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
//    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    /**
     * Se revisa si la imagen viene de la c‡mara (TAKE_PICTURE) 
     */

    if (requestCode == HACER_FOTO) {
            /**
             * A partir del nombre del archivo ya definido lo buscamos y creamos el bitmap
             * para el ImageView
             */
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)viewPrincipal.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(nombreFoto));
            /**
             * Para guardar la imagen en la galer’a, utilizamos una conexi—n a un MediaScanner
             */
            new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                private MediaScannerConnection msc = null; {
                    msc = new MediaScannerConnection(viewPrincipal.getContext(), this);
                    msc.connect();
                }
                public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                    msc.scanFile(nombreFoto, null);
                }
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    msc.disconnect();
                }
            };
        } 
    }
```

En el Activity principal, así funciona correctamente la aplicación, sin el login:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Pero si pongo algo en el método, como esto, para saber de donde viene la llamada, automáticamente se cierra la aplicación, cuando cierras la ventana de la cámara de fotos:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            //aqui falla la aplicacion
    String ventana= data.getStringExtra("ventana");
    if(!ventana.equals(null)) {
        if (ventana.equals("login")
                    {
                    //blablalba
                    }
                }
            }
```

Y el error que obtengo es:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.j2app.pruebafragments, PID: 27116
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=65546, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity
>   {com.j2app.pruebafragments/com.j2app.pruebafragments.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                  at
>   com.j2app.pruebafragments.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:93)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

El archivo `manifest` es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.j2app.pruebafragments">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Modal1Activity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar los permisos de tu aplicación? (archivo manifest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu programa busca de una manera muy extraña la existencia de "ventana":

```
String ventana = data.getStringExtra("ventana");
if (!ventana.equals(null)) {
  /* ... */
```

En ningún momento compruebas si existe la cadena "ventana", por lo que esa llamada falla devolviendo `null`, pero la comprobación que haces comprueba el contenido de la cadena (que es `null`) con una cadena que está alojada en `null` (un poco enrevesado).

Deberías hacer uso de [`Intent.hasExtra()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra(java.lang.String)):

```
if (data.hasExtra("ventana")) {
  String ventana = data.getStringExtra("ventana");
  /* ... */
}
```

Esa comprobación ya no te producirá el error que sufres.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.Lo he probado y no funciona, el código de la cámara funciona correctamente, tal y como esta en una aplicación sin los fragments, si lo uso en el activity principal.

Comment: Disculpa, me fui por otro lugar. Comprueba mi edición para ver si soluciona tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora funciona, llevo casi una semana perdida por un if

Comment: Un placer, a mí me han pasado cosas por el estilo, como que pasaba un dato en "A" y luego leía "B", así que en cuanto vi el código se me encendió la bombillita ;) no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta si te solucionó el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por el interés.

El archivo `manifest` es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.j2app.pruebafragments">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Modal1Activity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Pero no funcionaba correctamente la cámara (escribir en la SD) hasta que no añadí el método:

```
public void compruebaPermisoSD(Activity activity ) {
             // Check if we have write permission
             int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

             if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                 // We don't have permission so prompt the user
                 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                         activity,
                         PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                         REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                 );

             }
         }
```

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta para agregar esta información, no la añadas como respuesta. Gracias.